# Why cant I disable the DEBUG preprocessor symbol in a .NET standard project?

Tags: .net, .net-standard

If I try to turn off the DEBUG constant in a .NET standard project in the build tab of the projects properties in Visual Studio, it is immediately turned back on again - is there any way to turn it off?

Comment: how do you turn off the DEBUG constant?

Comment: normally its done in the build tab of the projects properties in VS

Comment: But I cannot repro your issue. I uncheck the DEBUG constant and build the project without a problem. VS2017 15.5, netstandard1.3

Comment: I saw one other SO user struggle with this.  VS2017 is a roach motel for bugs, use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.  Meanwhile try editing the project file with a text editor like Notepad.